# How to send complete form-urlencoded post data from preprocessor

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I know we can send/initialise the post data parameter variables from preprocessor but my requirement is i want to send complete post data/pay load which is shown in my screenshot from jsr223 preprocessor.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have `sampler` shorthand which stands for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) in the JSR223 PreProcessor
2. There is [HTTPArgument](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/HTTPArgument.html) class where you can specify name, value and whether they're encoded already or JMeter should perform the URL-encoding itself

So for each parameter you want to pass you need to add the line like:

```
sampler.getArguments().addArgument(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument('parameter_name', 'parameter_value', false))
```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)